# BeautifulSoup finding data with two different div classes

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse this html web page and I want specific data within the web page. I am using the findall function on this specific class. The only problem is that it is picking up unnecessary data on the side of the web site due to conflicting classes. I basically want to do a findall on div classes that contain "mainContent" and the item class name. I have only found how to find classes that contain "blank" or "blank". What would be the syntax of trying to find something that had a class name of "blank" and "blank"? Thank you!

Comment: Or how can I get all the subclasses within this specific div?

Answer (score 0):

Use [css selectors](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) instead of find_all():

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: UTF8 -*-from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_doc = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="alpha">not a match.</div>
  <div class="beta">not a match.</div>
  <div class="alpha beta">match.</div>
  <div class="beta alpha">match.</div>
  <p class="alpha beta">not match.</div>
</body>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

print(soup.select("div.alpha.beta"))
```

Comment: Basically, there is a div tag that has an id of "mainContent". I just want everything within that tag. I'm sure this would work, but I still unable to retrieve the data. Is there any more ideas you can give me" @

Comment: That's a different question. It's good practice to include "here's what I have," and, "here's the output I expect" in your questions.  `soup.select("div#mainContent")`